# Is there a way to tell TeXworks which compiler to default to when a .tex is opened?

Tags: texworks

Does something like:

```
#compiler=XeLaTeX%
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}%
\documentclass{<class name>}%
...
```

exist for compilation with TeXworks on a Windows platform?

Just a minor tweak that would save clicks.

Comment: `% !TEX program = XeLaTeX` at the top of the file should do it.

Comment: Thank you @HerbSchulz!